# Grouping Features permission

Tags: user-research, security, administration, roles

On the Wire-framing, you can see a list of sub-features under 'Accounts' and 'Products'.

Manager and Accountants are the user roles.

I am trying to figure how to reduce mental load by not showing sub-features as default. The sub-features could be collapsed by default. They simple tick the main Feature will apply all the sub-features. If user wish to customize the permission of sub-features then they expand the main feature which then show sub-features list. Or what do you suggest to improve this?

[image]

Comment: Related: [Editing user permissions within a group?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/82500/13161)

Comment: I would really like to see more about the research you made in order to decide which options would be necessary for each role and how often, prior to designing any interface. Usually the issue with role granting UIs is now how easy to use they are but how much time users must waste on them in real world contexts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option you may try is to add an "All Features" checkbox. When the checkbox is selected the sub-features are hidden. When the user deselects the checkbox, the sub-features are displayed, and the checkboxes on the feature level are hidden. See mockup bellow :

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4UYxo.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: It is good option. I think putting "All Features" checkbox next to User Roles (Manager, Accountants, etc) checkboxes look a bit confusing because it look like it has same responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an accordion control to allow expanding the category.

However, **I see a couple of problems here:**

- **If some options can be hidden, you need to handle partial selection**.  Otherwise, the rolled-up view would be misleading if only some of the categories were selected.  Partial selection will likely be difficult to implement clearly (and it might be a technical headache, too, if it goes beyond of the capabilities of a standard UI element on your platform).
- **The hierarchical relationship of the items isn't completely clear.**  For example, if I only saw the "Products" category, would I realize that "shipping settings" was a product setting?  This is not necessarily intuitive.  Categorizing stuff can be difficult, and there is not always an obvious organization of all the features.  This is not really a problem when all options are shown, but when some information is hidden, you rely on users being able to guess what a subcategory contains.

I would therefore favor not hiding the individual options.  **In security, clarity and precision are crucial.**  You need to know exactly what privileges you are giving to exactly what users.  I think that makes it worth showing more information on the page, even if it gets a bit cluttered.